# alexa The target device does not support the specified directive

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to implement the videoapp-starter template. I ran the following commands :

```
> ask new --template --url http://skilltemplates.com/templates.json
```

and

```
> ask deploy
```

After deploying the skill I am trying to test from the console. however, I am getting the same error as below. I have not modified the code revived from the template and trying to deploy as is.

```
The target device does not support the specified directive.
```

Alexa console error message
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations to the Alexa Simulator, some of the interfaces are not supported.
The Alexa Simulator **does not render the video playback**, but the Skill I/O section shows the `VideoApp` directives sent from your skill.

Try it on an actual device. Or check out [other ways](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#ways-to-test-an-alexa-skill) to test skill.

List of Alexa Simulator Limitations [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#alexa-simulator-limitations).